# create list of payees with 401k and roth contributions and sum matching amounts

Tags: sql-server, sum

I'm using sql-server.  I have a table of **401k** and **roth** contributions plus matching.  I need a query that will produce a list of payees with their contribution(s) listed under the correct column with the matching amounts sum'd. A contrib_type of 4 is 401k, a contrib_type of R is Roth.  The payees don't have to contribute to both.  They can contribute to the 401k and the Roth, the 401k or the Roth but if they have no 401k or Roth contribution, then the matching amount will just be the match + 0 (if that makes sense).

401k table:

```sql
create table 401k
(
  id char(32),
  contrib_type char(1),
  deduction_date datetime,
  contribution decimal(16,2),
  matching decimal(16,2),
  payee_id char(8)
);
```

sample data:

```sql
insert into 401k (id, contrib_type, deduction_date, contribution, matching, payee_id)
  values ('1','4','2022-12-30','21.00','10.00','Jones'),
         ('2','R','2022-12-30','15.00','7.00','Jones'),
         ('3','4','2022-12-30','50.00','7.00','Smith'),
         ('4','R','2022-12-30','60.00','15.00','Tyler')
```

my query so far:

```sql
select tradcontrib.payee_id, tradcontrib.contribution as contrib_401k,
sum(tradcontrib.matching + rothcontrib.matching) as matching,
rothcontrib.contribution as contrib_roth

from 401k as tradcontrib
   left outer join 401k as rothcontrib
        on rothcontrib.payee_id=tradcontrib.payee_id 
and rothcontrib.contrib_type='R' 
and rothcontrib.deduction_date='2022-12-30'

where tradcontrib.deduction_date='2022-12-30'
and tradcontrib.contrib_type='4'

group by tradcontrib.payee_id
```

the output I'm getting:

| payee_id | contrib_401k | matching | contrib_roth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | 21 | 17 | 15 |
| Smith | 50 | (null) | (null) |

The output I'd like to get:

| payee_id | contrib_401k | matching | contrib_roth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | 21 | 17 | 15 |
| Smith | 50 | 7 | 0 |
| Tyler | 0 | 15 | 60 |

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CASE expression to return the desired output, like this:

```
SELECT t.payee_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.contrib_type='4' THEN t.contribution  ELSE 0 END) as contrib_401k,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.contrib_type IN('4','R') THEN t.matching  ELSE 0 END) as matching,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.contrib_type ='R' THEN t.contribution   ELSE 0 END) as contrib_roth
FROM [401k] as t
GROUP BY t.payee_id
```

output:

| payee_id | contrib_401k | matching | contrib_roth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jones | 21.00 | 17.00 | 15.00 |
| Smith | 50.00 | 7.00 | 0.00 |
| Tyler | 0.00 | 15.00 | 60.00 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d9-4bHE4)

Answer (score 1):

Try including the condition `and tradcontrib.contrib_type='4'` in the left join clause instead, and not the where filter.

The filter works before the join happens and filters out any records for `Tyler` since the `contrib_type` is set to `R` for him.